# How can I expand the range of $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ in a piecewise manner?

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose I have a set of points $U = [0,2\pi]$ and I consider the set of points $\sin U = y$, which maps to $[-1,1]$. I now want to find an inverse for $\sin$ that allows me to recover all the points in $U$. But $\arcsin$ is only defined over $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

How can I define a new function $g(y)$ such that $g(\sin(U)) = U$ for all points in $[0,2\pi]$?

Similar question for $\arccos$.

Comment: I think you want to expand the _range_, not domain.

Comment: You can't, because for instance you want $g(0)$ to be both $0$ and $\pi$ at the same time. You can define a function that includes quadrant information, though (so that you can distinguish the first and second quadrants from each other, and the third and fourth quadrants from each other).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. $\sin$ isn't monotonic in any interval of lenght $>\pi$. Another viewpoint:
$$\sin(\pi/4) = \sin(3\pi/4)\implies \pi/4 = g(\sin(\pi/4)) = g(\sin(3\pi/4)) = 3\pi/4\ \  !!!!!!!$$

Answer (score 0):

If such a $g$ existed, we would have:
$$\frac\pi6=g\left(\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)\right)=g\left(\frac12\right)=\\g\left(\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)\right)=\frac{5\pi}6$$
Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sine function is periodic, let's say you want to calculate g(0.5), if it worked between $0 $ and $ 2\pi$, $g\left(0.5\right)$ is equal to $\frac{\pi }{6}$ and $\frac{5\pi }{6}$ But if you want it always to pick the least possible value you can make it periodic by defining $g\left(x\right)=\arcsin \left(\operatorname{mod}\left(x+1,2\right)-1\right)$ in that case $ g\left(0.5\right)=\frac{\pi }{6}$ although $\sin \left(\frac{5\pi }{6}\right) $ is also equal to $0.5$

Answer (score 0):

I'll tackle $sin(x)$ and $arcsin(x)$, using an algorithmic approach.  First, remember that you're wrapping around a trigonometric unit circle.

[image: trigonometric unit circle]

For example, $sin({\pi \over 6}) = sin({5\pi \over 6}) = sin(30\^\circ) = {1 \over 2}$.  However, if you look at the unit circle, you'll notice that $5\pi \over 6$ and $\pi \over 6$ are not the same points, but do yield the same solution for $sin(x)$.

We can visualize what's happening:

[image: desmos arcsin of sin of x]

You can think of 2 distinct steps occurring:

1. Points are mirrored between $0 \le x \le {\pi \over 2}$ and ${\pi \over 2} \le x \le \pi$ (over ${\pi \over 2}$), also $\pi \le x \le {3\pi \over 2}$ and ${3\pi \over 2} \le x \le 2\pi$ (over ${3\pi \over 2}$).

- $\quad \text{e.g.} \quad$ Using ${\pi \over 6}$, ${\pi} - {\pi \over 6} = {5\pi \over 6} \implies [{\pi \over 6}, {5\pi \over 6}]$

2. Every point, and mirrored point, are repeated every $2\pi$, forwards and backwards, infinitely.

- $\quad \text{e.g.} \quad {\pi \over 6} \implies [\dots, {-11\pi \over 6}, {-7\pi \over 6}, {\pi \over 6}, {5\pi \over 6}, {13\pi \over 6}, {17\pi \over 6}, \dots]$

From a *computer science* perspective, you can now program a solution:

1. For mirror points, you can use a modulus of $2\pi$ (leaving the remainder):

- $\quad \text{e.g.} \quad$ Using ${13\pi \over 6}$, $mod({13\pi \over 6}, {2\pi}) = {\pi \over 6} \qquad \text{(for positive values)}$

2. Check your result from above (i.e. ${\pi \over 6}$) with the 4 mirror ranges to determine how to mirror it:

- $\quad 0 \le x \le {\pi \over 2} \implies \pi - x \qquad \text{e.g.} \quad \pi - {\pi \over 6} = {5\pi \over 6}$
- $\quad {\pi \over 2} \le x \le \pi \implies -x + \pi \qquad \text{e.g.} \quad {-5\pi \over 6} + \pi = {\pi \over 6}$
- $\quad \pi \le x \le {3\pi \over 2} \implies 3\pi - x \qquad \text{e.g.} \quad 3\pi - {7\pi \over 6} = {11\pi \over 6}$
- $\quad {3\pi \over 2} \le x \le 2\pi \implies -x + 3\pi \qquad \text{e.g.}  \quad {-11\pi \over 6} + 3\pi = {7\pi \over 6}$

3. You might need to remove duplicates from overlapping ranges.
4. Then repeat all of these values for every $2\pi$, forward and backward in your desired range.

All of the points in your set $U$ should be a subset of your solution.  The algorithm should run quite fast.  And you can make it work for arbitrary ranges of values in $U$.